# Is it possible to add a background image to a <div> element on a JSP page? - Spring

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp

I have been looking for an answer for this for a few days now and can not seem to find a solution. Below is the example I am trying to implement, however no image is displayed. The aim is to have a responsive image that covers the entire page.

```
<div class="col-md-12 img-responsive" 
style="background-image:url(<c:url value='/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg' />);">
```

as far as I am aware this should work, I have resource mapping implemented and is working, I can tell this by navigating to the url and the image is displayed.

When placing this tag into the body element with the `background` attribute it displays the image but is not responsive and cuts the image as it pleases. I have tried styling this with bootstrap and using my own css, but anything I do makes no change/removes the image completely.

This url does also work with the `<img>` tag except then I can not overlay other elements with ease.

Ultimately my question is how can I get the div element to accept this url as a background image using pure css?

Any suggestions/prior experience would be welcomed.

**HTML code**

```
<body background="">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 header_bar">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                <a href="#" class="nav_login">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <a href="#" class="nav_login">log in</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">                                           
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 img-responsive" style="background-image:url(<c:url value='/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg' />);">
        </div>                                          

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the rendered HTML look like? Any errors in logs or consoles?

Comment: No errors and no warnings. I have added the HTML so you can see.

Comment: The HTML does not show the JSP having replaced the c:out with proper URL - is the HTML you show the actual view-source?

Comment: when I navigate to the localhost:8080/someapplication/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg, the image is displayed. I have just fixed this, although I am not sure how or why, removing the "img-respoinsive" bootstrap class resulted in the image loading properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Wisely for pointing me in the right direction,

This was solved by removing the bootstrap classes from the div that I was trying to add the background image to.

**The HTML**

```
<div class=" yourClassName" style="background-image:url(<c:url value='/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg' />)"></div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.yourClassName {
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Write a class to the div and write the css. set width and height for responsiveness. Remove the bootstrap classes "img-responsive".

i.e

HTML :

```
<div class="yourclassname">
```

CSS:

```
.yourclassname
{
background-image:<c:url value="/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg" />
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This link doesn't work as it is a JSP page in a Spring web application, resources have to be fetched through the <c:url value="" /> tag. However, trying your suggestion (removing the bootstrap class) did result in the image displaying! I am not sure why "img-responsive" would cause the image not to load, but thank you!

Comment: sure i have edited the answer. while using bootstrap , sometimes we have to tweak the code accordingly with the html we use. writing a custom css always helps.

Comment: if my answer helped you, dont forget to upvote or accept answer :) thank you.

Comment: Yes, however the css that you provided would not work as the <c:url> tag would not be accessible by the css file. It has to be declared on the jsp page. like so:  <div class=" yourClassName" style="background-image:url(<c:url value='/resources/img/abstract-ice.jpeg' />)"></div>